# Using CNAME DNS Entry to call AWS Lambda Function

Tags: dns, aws-lambda, cname

I currently have a lambda function deployed on AWS. The URL for the Lambda is `https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/stage_name_here`.

I created a CNAME entry in my DNS which points
`my.custom.name.com` to the base of the Lambda: `https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/`. I DO NOT OWN THE DOMAIN `name.com`. This is purely a CNAME reference which my DNS will resolve to the lambda base. If I run `nslookup` on `my.custom.name.com`, it does resolve properly and points to `https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/`

I can properly use the lambda through Postman when calling `https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/stage_name_here`, however if I try to use any variation of `my.custom.name.com/stage_name_here`, it returns with

```
{
  'message': 'forbidden'
}
```

My understanding is that when I attempt to use that CNAME to make a request, it first goes to my DNS. My DNS resolves that CNAME to the lambda base address. My understanding is that AWS would have no knowledge of `my.custom.name.com` as my DNS only uses that to know where to send a request.

An analogy for my understanding would be that I'm trying to send a letter to an address: `address1`. Instead of writing address1 on the letter, I write `address2`. When the mailman gets my letter, he asks his boss where `address2` is, and his boss tells him `address2 = address1`. Then he delivers the letter to address1.

In that analogy, `address2` does not need to actually exists for this transaction to occurr. Unless I misunderstand, AWS API Gateway REQUIRES that `address2` exists because the letters first goes to `address2` and THEN goes to `address1`.

What seems to be happening is that AWS somehow knows that `address2` was part of the equation because it denies the request when `address2` is used instead of `address1`.

What is the difference in this scenario, and how can I set up the DNS CNAME and AWS to get scenario 1 to happen?

Comment: Did you do a "custom Domain Name" via API Gateway? If not, you'll want to :)

Comment: From what I understand, that won't work for internal DNS CNAME references, only external domains. When trying to create a custom domain in API Gateway, it requires an SSL Certificate. It seems the way to get this is through your registrar which does not apply to an internal CNAME reference. As per this documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html it states "You must have a registered internet domain name in order to set up custom domain names for your APIs"

Comment: You need to create a custom domain name because in front of API Gateway is Cloudfront. You are right that this cannot be done for internal networks, however that was not mentioned in your problem statement above. you do need to OWN your domain name, and still setup a custom domain name via api gateway. @Arun K has outlined the process exactly.

Comment: "AWS would have no knowledge of my.custom.name.com as my DNS only uses that to know where to send a request."

No.  The initial TCP connection to the webserver uses the IP address, but the HTTP request sends the domain name as Host.  Often a single IP will have many sites distinguished only by Host name.

You can see this by comparing `host www.amazon.com` and `curl -vvv www.amazon.com`

Answer (score 2):

AWS API gateway console has a built in mechanism called `custom domains`. It is exactly what you need. you need to set that up as @LostJon pointed out.

Basic Steps are:

1. create an SSL certificate using Amazon ACM
2. Create a custom domain from API gateway console such as `api.example.com`, During this step, select the SSL certificate for your domain obtained via Step 1
3. create a `basepath` to point the `basepath` to your API. for e.g base path `/payment` is pointing to your api, which makes it accessible via `https://api.example.com/payment`
   this process will also give you a cloudfront distribution address for e.g d3fgrtgh@cloudfront.net`
4. Goto Route53 (or your domain register) and create an `A` record to point the subdomain `api.example.com` to the cloudfront distribution address e.g d3fgrtgh@cloudfront.net`

reference:
https://hackernoon.com/how-to-setup-subdomain-for-aws-api-gateway-d526a9fd6722

Comment: I've edited my original post to be more clear, but I do not own a domain and cannot own a domain in this process. Owning a domain seems to be a required part of using API Gateway custom domains.

Comment: you are right. you need a domain in order to obtain a SSL certificate